# Best rules to get data with Contain

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 3 ORM has changed and I can't find the proper way to select needed data from the database.

In CakePHP 2, I use `contain('User.name','User.id')`, but In CakePHP 3 this code doesn't work.

So how can I select only `id` and `name` from User?

The code:

```
$query = $data->find()->contain(['Users'])->execute()->fetchAll('assoc');
// I want only user.id and user.name.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$articles = $this->Model->find()
        ->select(['fields_you_want_from_this_Model'])
        ->contain(['Assoc_Model'  => function($q) {
            return $q
                ->select(['fields_you_want_from_the_associated_model']);
        }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

U must take a look about this page: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#passing-conditions-to-contain

In certain case you must use autoFields method.

Be carefull with contain when u select few fields in the callable, u always have to select the foreign key also:

> When you limit the fields that are fetched from an association, you must ensure that the foreign key columns are selected. Failing to select foreign key fields will cause associated data to not be present in the final result.